# Inline input fields behave differently in browsers

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a quantity selector on a webpage. I used a trick to make them inline without any gaps.

```
<div id="quantitybar">                        
    <span class="inputwrapper">
        <button id="piece_plus">+</button>
        <input type="text" value="1" id="pieces" />
        <button id="piece_minus">-</button>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />                        
</div>
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86sZ7/

It looks nice in Chrome, but in Firefox the bottom border of the text imput field is missing a piece. If I set overflow: hidden to the span then it looks OK, but the submit button is shifted down.
I want to make it look the same in Chrome and Firefox. Plus: it would be nice to have the submit button align with the other inputs too, because now it's a little off.

Comment: They look the same on my chrome and firefox browsers

Comment: In my case also it is working perfectly on both FF and chrome.